# Windows Phone Phone Capabilities used by Application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a class library which is a set of helper classes to develop windows phone 7 applications.

One of core helper classes I have in this library is responsible to provide location service functionalities, so it uses ILocationWatcher and references to System.Device.

Now the problem is even if I don't use this helper class (i.e. LocationWatcher will never be started) after submitting the app in marketplace, it shows "Location services" as one of capabilities my app is using.

I believe the way marketplace detects this, is more or less analysing all codes and libraries within the project.

How can we somehow override this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capabilites are detected using static analysis when your xap is submitted to the marketplace.

The location capabiltiy is reported if you reference the assembly `System.Device` and use the namespace `System.Device.Location`.

All assemblies in your XAP are analysed. *Even ones you get from 3rd parties.*

If you don't want the capability to be reported in the marketplace then remove the references which triggers its detection.
You may want to consider how you structure your shared/common libraries/code with this in mind.

Comment: so in other words you are saying that there is absolutely noway of overriding it (ofcourse other than separating location helpers from the library), right?

Comment: yep, there is no way of saying "this code isn't used by this app" other than by removing it from the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your used capabilities with the [free capability detection tool supplied with the second Mango SDK beta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180730%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). If you use location without defining it at the WMAppManifest.xml, the user will get a "Access denied" message and your app will throw an [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx). Afaik there is no possible way to circumvent this behaviour. It is meant as a security feature to warn users before they install a app so they can check on marketplace what features the application will want to use.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe it is analyzing the code. Rather it is using the manifest's Capabilities section to determine what is required. You can learn more about that section here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509(v=vs.92).aspx#BKMK_Capabilities

Does the application's manifest include `ID_CAP_LOCATION`? If it does, and you aren't using it - it can safely be removed.

Comment: All capabilites are detected when the xap is submitted to the marketplace. The values you put in the manifest yourself are overridden. They are useful only when testing/debugging.

Comment: Huh, that comes as a surprise to me. Egg in my face!